# How can I disable the Last-Modified header for static file on nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Even if I add these options, the response contains Last-Modified header. I'm testing with nginx + tornado.

```
sendfile off;
if_modified_since off;
expires off;
etag off;
```

Comment: You can do this with `add_header Last-Modified "";` See [this answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/287869/how-do-i-alter-the-last-modified-header-on-nginx)

Comment: I have tried it. I added it to http directive and server directive, but it does not work for me.

Comment: It would not work if you have `add_header` in "lower" level location blocks. E.g. if you have `location ~ \.css$ { add_header something else`. This is how `add_header` works, you need to put desired directives in the same level or it won't add/alter header. To avoid configuration pitfalls with `add_header` you can use [this module](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module)

Comment: `location ^~ /static/ { add_header Last-Modified "";  ... }` This actually works for me

Answer (score -1):

To sum up from the comments:

In generally you can place this into `location`-block:

```
location ... {
    add_header    Last-Modified '';

    # or if you a fan of double-quotes
    add_header    Last-Modified "";
}
```

But be aware - you have to define this for **each** location-block.